# Override a method already added via expandoMetaClass

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I am having trouble understanding how the GroovyClassLoader cache works with expando Methods.

In particular, I expected the following code to give a different output for each call to Number.test(), yet this is not the case.

```
int i = 1

Number.metaClass.test = {
  return "A string"
}
println i.test()

println GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.getMetaClass(Number.class)
Number.metaClass = null
println GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.getMetaClass(Number.class)

Number.metaClass.test = {
  return "Another String"
}
println i.test()

println GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.getMetaClass(Number.class)
GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(Number.class)
println GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.getMetaClass(Number.class)

Number.metaClass.test = {
  return "Yet another String"
}
println i.test()
```

Output:

```
A string
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass@3571b748[class java.lang.Number]
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@7748410a[class java.lang.Number]
A string
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass@37f1104d[class java.lang.Number]
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@55740540[class java.lang.Number]
A string
```

**Edit:**

I tried some more things. It looks like my system is acting quite strangely. Given the following code:

```
def i = 1

i.class

Number.metaClass.test = {
  return "A string"
}
println i.test()

Number.metaClass = null
Number.metaClass.test = {
  return "Another String"
}
println i.test()

GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(Number.class)
Number.metaClass.test = {
  return "Yet another String"
}
println i.test()
```

When I execute it on my system, it works as expected (getting 3 different strings in output) but it fails (3 x `A string`) if I comment the supposedly useless `i.class`.

However, if I execute it on groovy-console.appspot.com, it gives me the expected output with or without that line...

I'm kind of at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

When you created the `int i = 9`, it created an object with the current `Number.metaClass`. It accepts creating a new method (read `Number.metaClass.test = { "A string" }`), but won't allow overload already existing ones. You can change the object's metaclass instead:

```
int i = 1

Number.metaClass.test = { "A string" }
assert i.test() == "A string"

Number.metaClass = null

i.metaClass.test = { "Another String" }
assert i.test() == "Another String"

GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(Number.class)
assert i.test() == "Another String"

i.metaClass.test = { "Yet another String" }
assert i.test() == "Yet another String"
```

---

Needing to invoke `i.class` looks like a bug to me... Taking a look at jira I saw some unresolved and opened bugs. I thought yours looked similar to these ones:

> Overriding methods on a Java class metaClass doesn't take effect until instance metaClass is changed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5065
>
> Using metaClass to override methods in class hierarchy does not work as expected: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3942
>
> Overriding methods via .metaClass doesn't behave consistently:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6847
>
> Removing a metaClass method:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4189

---

The first part of my answer works if you consider a concrete class:

```
class Echo {}
Echo.metaClass.test = { "A string" }
def i = new Echo()
assert i.test() == "A string"

Echo.metaClass = null
Echo.metaClass.test = { "Another String" }
assert i.test() == "A string"

i.metaClass.test = { "Another String" }
assert i.test() == "Another String"

i.metaClass.test = { "Yet another String" }
assert i.test() == "Yet another String"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it pushed me to investigate some more, but as you can see in my edit, I'm not sure the explanation is as simple as yours.

Comment: Thanks again. I had seen GROOVY-4189, which I tried using to circumvent the issue but doesn't explain it. I believe it is indeed very much linked to GROOVY-6847, though, so thanks for pointing it out. I upvoted your answer, but I keep the question unresolved since the behaviour remains unexplained. Thanks again.

Comment: If no bugs match your case, consider opening a JIRA ticket